# How to retrieve values off of SuiteScript 2.0 Suitelet for POST?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a form being created under the GET method for a Suitelet I created. Then, in the POST portion of the code, I am attempting to retrieve a free-form text field value off of the relevant form. How can this be done? I attempted to get the value in such a way, but apparently it cannot be gotten off of the form object, however, I am not sure how this is done in SuiteScript as the tutorial I went through on SuiteScripts did not cover how to retrieve the Suitelet values in SuiteScript 2.0.

```
if (request.method == 'GET'){
  var form = serverWidget.createForm({
    title: 'Sales Order Update'
  });

  var financingPriceField = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_sdr_financing_price',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
    label: 'Financing Price'
  });

  var submitButton = form.addSubmitButton({
    label: 'Save SO Data'
  });

  response.writePage(form);
}

else // If POSTing
{
  var salesOrder = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    id: 9976 // Using hard-coded id for testing only
    isDynamic: true
  });

  // This portion of the code is failing to get any value
  // When attempting to do so will result in a TypeError
  // 'Cannot call method 'getValue' of undefined
  var financingPrice = form.getValue('custpage_sdr_financing_price');

  // Will save sales order and copy value to SO in code below, not shown in example
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SS1.0 you get the value from the request

```
request.getParameter('custpage_sdr_financing_price');
```

Comment: In 2.0, the Request object has all the parameters in a property, and you can access all body fields from your Form through that, e.g. `var price = context.request.parameters.custpage_sdr_financing_price;` where `context` is the reference to the argument of your `onRequest` function.

Comment: Sorry. @erictgrubaugh Answered from my phone and barely saw it was SS2.0. You should make an answer of your comment since it's the correct one for this question.

Comment: Hi, what about get sublist text value from post request, not the sublist value. 
Do we have something similiar like this: context.request.getSublistText({group:'', name:'', line:''});